# Error while creating native image with GraalVM on Windows 11

Tags: java, windows-11, graalvm-native-image

When I try to create native image on Windows 11 computer I get the error below. And my environment specifications are like this:

- OS : Windows 11 Enterprise 64-bit (22621) (Language : English)
- GraalVM : ce-java11-22.1.0 (Windows amd64)
- Microsoft Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 (16.11.24)
- Maven 3.8.1
- x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX960.png)

Is there anything wrong with windows 11? Also this same error occurs on GraalVM version 22.3.1 too. And I created an issue on GitHub https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/6438

I tried to change GraalVM version and reinstalled Visual C++ Build Tools but they didnt help